# sql question regarding fine tuning a query

Tags: sql

I have a stored procedure that returns multiple columns. like colA colB colC .... colL
Can I write another query to get the same columns but if colC/colB <10%  i.e WHERE filter by 10%. Basically the same columns as returned by the stored procedure should be shown but only now colC/colB should be <10%. I cannot modify the stored procedure as it is used in another application and I am just getting values from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use table variable (@) or temp table (#), because you can't select directly from the result set of a stored procdure:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (colA int, colB int, colC int, ...)

INSERT INTO @table
EXEC StoreProcedureName

SELECT * FROM @table WHERE colC * 10 < colB
```

Answer (score 1):

That should work.  I might suggest adding a WHERE clause like this:

```
WHERE (colC * 10) < ColB
```

That would prevent you from having to do percentages and stuff.

You could likely just filter the results in your code as well.

BTW... this is how I converted colC/ColB < 10%:

```
C/B < 10%
C/B < .1     (convert percentage to decimal)
C   < .1B    (multiply both sides by B)
10C < B      (multiply both sides by 10)
```

You could even write the new stored procedure to take in a variable for the percentage amount you want to return.  The where clause would then be WHERE (colC * @percentage) < colB

Comment: I think the issue is that the stored procedure cannot be modified, so you can't apply the WHERE clause directly to the results.

Comment: Ok.  Good point. If so, your solution works.  If he can write a new stored procedure, then he could use this solution.

Comment: I do like the colC * 10 trick.  Nicely circumvents problems with varying datatypes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the issue here is that you can't get the results of a stored procedure using an inline SELECT statement; correct?  In other words, you'd like to be able to say,

```
SELECT * FROM myProc WHERE (colcC / colB) < .1
```

But *that doesn't work,* because you can't treat a stored procedure like a table in this context.

The best solution to this problem is to create a new stored procedure that does two things:

1) Copy the results of the procedure into a temp table, like this:

```
INSERT INTO #myTempTable EXEC myProcedure
```

2) Select the rows you're interested in, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM #myTempTable WHERE (colC * 10) < colB
```

(Borrowed the colC * 10 trick from Narnian.)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks all. I ll use this and check.